# Scrolling not working on listview in some cases - JQM

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I've searched the net and this site but I did not find a solution that fits my problem.

***Situation*** : - I have a JQM basic page, with listviews on it.
            - A few events deal with swipe etc

***Problem*** : - When I scroll the list by clicking an item, holding it and swiping down or up, it scrolls perfectly, but when I release the screen then scroll again on that listitem, it just does nothing.

**I made a jsfiddle to reproduce it on mobile : http://jsfiddle.net/WQdJk/9/**
**And here's the code** :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
```

```
<script>
   $(document).on('click', 'ul li a', function(){
       $('h3').css("color", "orange");
   });

   $(document).on( "swipeleft swiperight", function( e ) {
       if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  )     
           $("h3").css("color","blue");
       else 
           $("h3").css("color","green");
   });
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">    
        <h3>TEST</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" style="margin-top:50px; height:500px; overflow:scroll;">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="home">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="check">Tâches</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="calendar">Rendez-vous</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="grid">Dossiers</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Paramètres</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="home">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="check">Tâches</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="calendar">Rendez-vous</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="grid">Dossiers</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Paramètres</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="home">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="check">Tâches</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="calendar">Rendez-vous</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="grid">Dossiers</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Paramètres</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="home">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="check">Tâches</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="calendar">Rendez-vous</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="grid">Dossiers</a></li>
            <li><a data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Paramètres</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Can you please give me advices or tips on how to fix this? It seems like the button goes on standby after scrolling...

Thanks in advance

---

### PS : actually this happens only when scrolling on an item's text, releasing scroll, scroll again from that very item but not on the text (on the button itself but outside anchor's text)

Comment: Just to clarify, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I want my list to go up and down in every scenario if I scroll it instead of having the button frozen and the list not moving.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem on iPhone 5 safari. Scroll works as well as swipe.

Comment: Well I could not test it on iOS, but on my Google Nexus 5, or other Android devices, I encountered the issue.

Comment: Note that Android suffers `overflow: scroll` issues. If you remove it an let content div handle scrolling, the problem should disappear.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know, thanks for your answers everyone.

Comment: I tested the code without the overflow:scroll and then with overflow set to auto, but the problem persists. :(

Comment: Hello again,

I have updated jsfiddle, as I did a few other tests.
Finally I pointed out that it is the swipe function that prevent the list from scrolling, but I don't understand why...

Any ideas? I'd like to have the swipe functionality in order to swipe between pages or open side menus without my lists getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in JQM that has been resolved but is not yet implemented https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5534

Basically the min distance measured by the swipe event must take into account the pixel density of the device. So in JQM's case, the following change to touch.js will solve the issue:

```
horizontalDistanceThreshold = window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ? 15 : 30;
verticalDistanceThreshold = window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ? 15 : 30;
```

Comment: I am also having a similar problem with some users reporting that the listview is frozen. I am not able to find any touch.js in my JQM folder. Where can I find this?